# Зачем популярные ресурсы ставят ограничение по размеру загружаемого файла(картинки)?

Tags: загрузка

Если учесть, что полученную картинку можно спокойно уменьшить ресурсами языка программирования, возникает вышеуказанный вопрос. Я понимаю, что это ресурсоемкое дело, но большинство серверов все равно делает несколько копий изображений в разных размерах. К тому же, на таких серверах подобное действие не должно вызвать проблемы.
Спасибо!

Comment: Наверно вопрос "риторический".

Comment: Наверно ответ - так проще. Я могу сказать только за свой сервис, что если мне подсовывают картинище огромное - я преобразую его в более маленькое. Правда это было реализовано не мной.

Comment: @nick_n_a, это понятно. Вопрос  в том, что они сайте ставят ограничение до 512 кб. Обычные непользователи не умеет сжимать изображение, этим самым вызывают проблему. Мой вопрос звучал, зачем они усложняю жизнь, если можно сжать на входе

Comment: В теории, если бан ставить на клиенте - это должно секономить трафик и как следствие - загруженость сервера. Если бан на сервере - это только увеличит трафик.